# Difficulty modifying an array environment

Tags: environments, theorems, arrays

I have an array that I had past help on and now I am attempting to modify that array. However, when doing so, parts of my "theorem" keep getting shifted to the next line.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,array}
\newcommand{\twolinebrace}{\rlap{$\smash{\raisebox{.5\height}{\bigg\}}}$}}
\newlength{\LHS}\newlength{\RHS}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}p{\LHS}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{$}p{\RHS}<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
Let $\{A_{\alpha \colon \alpha \in A}\}$ and $\{B_{\beta \colon \beta \in  B}\}$ be families of subsets if a set $X$. Then:
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}
\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\\
             \begin{array}                                                                       {>{\bfseries}p{2em}@{\quad}M@{\quad$=$\quad}N}
  (a) & \big(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} A_{\alpha}\big) \cup \big(\bigcup_{\beta\in B} B_{\beta}\big) & \bigcup_{(\alpha,\beta)} A_{\alpha} \cup B_{\beta}\\
  (b) & \bigg(\bigcap_{\alpha \in A A_{\alpha}} \bigg) \cap \bigg(\bigcap_{\beta \in B B_{\beta}} \bigg) &  \bigcap_{(\alpha,\beta)} A_{\alpha} \cap B_{\beta} 
\end{array}\right\} & {\text{Associative Laws}} \\
\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{array}{>{\bfseries}p{2em}@{\quad}M@{\quad$=$\quad}N}
  (c) & X \cup (Y \cup Z) & (X \cup Y) \cup Z \\
  (d) & X \cap (Y \cap Z) & (X \cap Y) \cap Z 
\end{array}\right\} & {\text{Associative Laws}} \\
\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{array}{>{\bfseries}p{2em}@{\quad}M@{\quad$=$\quad}N}
  (e) & X \cup (Y \cap Z) & (X \cup Y) \cap (X \cup Z) \\
  (f) & X \cap (Y \cup Z) & (X \cap Y) \cup (X \cap Z)
\end{array}\right\} & {\text{Distributive Laws}} \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

I needed to add to my array, and now I am having additional problems. Now, the "text" 'Associative Laws', 'Distributive Laws', and 'de Morgan's Laws' are not being displayed correctly. Here is my latest MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,array}
\newcommand{\twolinebrace}{\rlap{$\smash{\raisebox{.5\height}{\bigg\}}}$}}
\newlength{\LHS}\newlength{\RHS}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}p{\LHS}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{$}p{\RHS}<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
Let $\{A_{\alpha \colon \alpha \in A}\}$ and $\{B_{\beta \colon \beta \in  B}\}$ be families of subsets of a set~$X$. Then:
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}
\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{array}{>{\bfseries}p{2em}@{\quad}M@{\quad$=$\quad}N}
(a) & X \cup Y &  Y \cup X \\
  (b) & X \cap Y &  X \cap Y
\end{array}\right\} & {\text{Commutative Laws}} \\
\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{array}{>{\bfseries}p{2em}@{\quad}M@{\quad$=$\quad}N}
(c) & X \cup (Y \cup Z) & (X \cup Y) \cup Z \\
  (d) & X \cap (Y \cap Z) & (X \cap Y) \cap Z 
\end{array}\right\} & {\text{Associative Laws}} \\
\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{array}{>{\bfseries}p{2em}@{\quad}M@{\quad$=$\quad}N}
(e) & X \cup (Y \cap Z) & (X \cup Y) \cap (X \cup Z) \\
  (f) & X \cap (Y \cup Z) & (X \cap Y) \cup (X \cap Z)
\end{array}\right\} & {\text{Distributive Laws}} \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{theorem}
```

Any additional help would be greatly appreciated in this matter.

Comment: for a beginning, the two new lengths, `\LHS` and `\RHS`, haven't been assigned any values, so those lengths are effectively zero.  there may be other problems as well, but zero lengths are useful only in very special circumstances, and as widths for table columns isn't one of those.

Comment: as in your original example, `\LHS` and `\RHS` are still zero width.  this new example would benefit from either of the answers that have already been given.  or you could `\setlength{\LHS}{.75in}\setlength{\RHS}{1.5in}` and at least get something that doesn't overprint.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In my preamble file, I had the following:                                                \newlength{\LHS}\newlength{\RHS} and added your suggested code below that, yet when I compiled I still had the "overprinting" problem. Or am I still doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following is a little cleaner:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,amsthm,array}
\newcommand{\twolinebrace}{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\\\\\end{array}\right\}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
Let $\{A_{\alpha \colon \alpha \in A}\}$ and $\{B_{\beta \colon \beta \in  B}\}$ be families of subsets if a set~$X$. Then:
\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}
    \begin{array}{>{\bfseries}p{2em}@{\quad}r@{{}={}}l}
      (a) & 
        \big(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} A_{\alpha}\big) \cup \big(\bigcup_{\beta\in B} B_{\beta}\big) & % LHS
        \bigcup_{(\alpha,\beta)} A_{\alpha} \cup B_{\beta} \\ % RHS
      (b) & 
        \big(\bigcap_{\alpha \in A} A_{\alpha} \big) \cap \big(\bigcap_{\beta \in B} B_{\beta} \big) & % LHS
        \bigcap_{(\alpha,\beta)} A_{\alpha} \cap B_{\beta} % RHS
    \end{array} & \twolinebrace\text{Associative Laws} \\
    \begin{array}{>{\bfseries}p{2em}@{\quad}r@{{}={}}l}
      (c) & 
        X \cup (Y \cup Z) & % LHS
        (X \cup Y) \cup Z \\ % RHS
      (d) & 
        X \cap (Y \cap Z) & % LHS
        (X \cap Y) \cap Z % RHS
    \end{array} & \twolinebrace\text{Associative Laws} \\
    \begin{array}{>{\bfseries}p{2em}@{\quad}r@{{}={}}l}
      (e) & 
        X \cup (Y \cap Z) & % LHS
        (X \cup Y) \cap (X \cup Z) \\ % RHS
      (f) & 
        X \cap (Y \cup Z) & % LHS
        (X \cap Y) \cup (X \cap Z) % RHS
    \end{array} & \twolinebrace\text{Distributive Laws}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Note that using an `array` like this (or even just setting the content in a display `\[`...`\]`) it can't be broken across the page boundary. If you wish to overcome this limitation, you'll have to set the display as a list rather, or break it up into separate chunks containing each "law pair", allowing content to break inbetween.

Answer (score 2):

Just a different flavor to the above though I do not recommend it for multiple uses. The reason being that you would have to adjust the labels each time. But anyhow here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
Let $\{A_{\alpha \colon \alpha \in A}\}$ and $\{B_{\beta \colon \beta \in  B}\}$ be families of subsets if a set $X$. Then:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries(\alph*)]
    \item $\big(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} A_{\alpha}\big) \cup \big(\bigcup_{\beta\in B} B_{\beta}\big) = \bigcup_{(\alpha,\beta)} A_{\alpha} \cup B_{\beta}$
    \item $\big(\bigcap_{\alpha \in A} A_{\alpha} \big) \cap \big(\bigcap_{\beta \in B} B_{\beta} \big)=\bigcap_{(\alpha,\beta)} A_{\alpha} \cap B_{\beta}$
                \makebox(0,0){\put(0,10ex){%
               $\left.\rule{0pt}{5ex}\right\}$ Associative Laws}}
    \item $X \cup (Y \cup Z)= (X \cup Y) \cup Z$  
  \item $X \cap (Y \cap Z) = (X \cap Y) \cap Z$
                \makebox(0,0){\put(7em,10ex){%
               $\left.\rule{0pt}{5ex}\right\}$ Associative Laws}}
  \item $X \cup (Y \cap Z) = (X \cup Y) \cap (X \cup Z)$
  \item $X \cap (Y \cup Z) = (X \cap Y) \cup (X \cap Z)$
                \makebox(0,0){\put(4.25em,10ex){%
               $\left.\rule{0pt}{5ex}\right\}$ Distributive Laws}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]